# CASE inside ORDER BY with multiple columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-order-by, case

I want to conditionally order a query

```
ORDER BY 
CASE
WHEN TRUE THEN users.name, users.lastname END
```

but it raises syntax error `syntax error near or at ","`.

Examle below works like a charm

```
ORDER BY 
CASE
WHEN TRUE THEN users.name END
```

I've also tried

```
ORDER BY 
CASE
WHEN TRUE THEN "users.name, users.lastname" END
```

which raises `"users.name, users.lastname"` does not exist

```
    ORDER BY 
CASE
WHEN TRUE THEN "users"."name", "users"."lastname" END
```

this raises `syntax error at ","`

how to put multiple columns inside CASE inside ORDER BY?

Comment: `case when true ... ` does not make any sense to me. You can remove the complete `CASE` expression. `CASE WHEN TRUE THEN users.name END` is the same as `users.name`

Comment: I simplified my 'real' issue to make question easier to read. I have many more `CASE` conditions which actually checks for something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [ROW constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) in order to compose few columns together

```
ORDER BY 
CASE
WHEN TRUE THEN ROW(users.name, users.lastname) END
```

if there is more than 1 value inside `ROW()` you can skip `ROW` keyword. Here is shorter version with syntactic sugar:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE
WHEN TRUE THEN (users.name, users.lastname) END
```

Comment: You might want to explain what this achieves and why it works (because this is Postgres specific)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure what are you asking about?

Comment: You should explain _why_ adding the parentheses works in Postgres (because this would not work in other DBMS)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't know why. there is still place for better answer :)

Comment: @FilipBartuzi [Row Constructors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) and _"The key word ROW is optional when there is more than one expression in the list."_

Answer (score 1):

Just use two `case` expressions:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN TRUE THEN users.name END),
         (CASE WHEN TRUE THEN users.lastname END)
```

Comment: in my "real world example" I have multiple case conditions (not just true). Would I have to do multiple `CASE` inside multiple `CASE`?

Comment: @FilipBartuzi . . . Yes, you would need additional `CASE` statements. This method is more general than the `ROW()` constructor method (which is clever and applicable), because this can change the ordering (`ASC` vs `DESC`) for each key.